# Similar method for measuring execution time in R and C++

Tags: c++, r, similarity, execution-time

Which method for measuring execution time in R is the most similar to method clock() in C++ ?

I use the sys.time().

What do you think, if I can compare execution times in the C ++ programming language with R ?

Comment: Using `Sys.time()` seems reasonable to me.  What are you trying to benchmark in R and C++?

Comment: If on Linux, you can use the time command to measure total execution time. Example: time ./a.out where a.out is your executable.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways to answer.**

**The first (short one)**

To get the time to execute a statement, or block of code, in R you can use 'system.time'. In the specification - "Return CPU (and other) times that expr used." - and it is close to `clock()` in C++ because standard said about clock - "Returns the processor time consumed by the program."

So, my answer is: You can compare execution times in the C++ (with clock) and R (with system.time()).

**The second (quite long)**

I have oppened **R-3.3.1.tar.gz** file and in folder **src** fund some files that looks like related to this issue.

In file `system.c` (declaration):

```
 void R_setStartTime(void); /* in sys-unix.c */
```

In file `in sys-unix.c` (definition):

```cpp
void R_setStartTime(void)
{
#ifdef HAVE_SYSCONF
    clk_tck = (double) sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
#else
# ifndef CLK_TCK
/* this is in ticks/second, generally 60 on BSD style Unix, 100? on SysV
 */
#  ifdef HZ
#   define CLK_TCK HZ
#  else
#   define CLK_TCK 60
#  endif
# endif /* not CLK_TCK */
    clk_tck = (double) CLK_TCK;
#endif
    /* printf("CLK_TCK = %d\n", CLK_TCK); */
    StartTime = currentTime();
}
```

and

```cpp
/* NOTE
   This used to use times() for elapsed times, which is measured in
   clock ticks (which can overflow).  It is possible this version uses
   time() and so is in seconds.  But even Cygwin has gettimeofday.
 */
attribute_hidden
void R_getProcTime(double *data)
{
    /* docs say this is rounded to the nearest ms */
    double et = currentTime() - StartTime;
    data[2] = 1e-3 * rint(1000*et);
#ifdef HAVE_GETRUSAGE
    /* all known current OSes */
    struct rusage self, children;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &self);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &children);
    data[0] = (double) self.ru_utime.tv_sec +
    1e-3 * (self.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000);
    data[1] = (double) self.ru_stime.tv_sec +
    1e-3 * (self.ru_stime.tv_usec/1000);
    data[3] = (double) children.ru_utime.tv_sec +
    1e-3 * (children.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000);
    data[4] = (double) children.ru_stime.tv_sec +
    1e-3 * (children.ru_stime.tv_usec/1000);
#else
    /* Not known to be currently used */
    struct tms timeinfo;
    times(&timeinfo);
    data[0] = fround(timeinfo.tms_utime / clk_tck, 3);
    data[1] = fround(timeinfo.tms_stime / clk_tck, 3);
    data[3] = fround(timeinfo.tms_cutime / clk_tck, 3);
    data[4] = fround(timeinfo.tms_cstime / clk_tck, 3);
#endif
}
```

And `currentTime()` that defined in `times.c` is as follows:

```cpp
double currentTime(void)
{
    double ans = NA_REAL;

#ifdef HAVE_TIMESPEC_GET
    struct timespec tp;
    int res = timespec_get(&tp, TIME_UTC);
    if(res != 0)
    ans = (double) tp.tv_sec + 1e-9 * (double) tp.tv_nsec;
#elif defined(HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME) && defined(CLOCK_REALTIME)
    /* Has 2038 issue if time_t: tv.tv_sec is 32-bit. */
    struct timespec tp;
    int res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
    if(res == 0)
    ans = (double) tp.tv_sec + 1e-9 * (double) tp.tv_nsec;

#elif defined(HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY)
    /* Mac OS X, mingw.org, used on mingw-w64.
       Has 2038 issue if time_t: tv.tv_sec is 32-bit.
     */
    struct timeval tv;
    int res = gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    if(res == 0)
    ans = (double) tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * (double) tv.tv_usec;

#else
    /* No known current OSes */
    time_t res = time(NULL);
    if(res != (time_t)(-1)) /* -1 must be an error as the real value -1
                   was ca 1969 */
    ans = (double) res;
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_POSIX_LEAPSECONDS
    /* No known current OSes */
    /* Disallowed by POSIX (1988-):
       http://www.mail-archive.com/leapsecs@rom.usno.navy.mil/msg00109.html
       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time
    */
    if (!ISNAN(ans)) {
    ans -= n_leapseconds;
    }
#endif
    return ans;
}
```

So, we can see that implimentation of time detection in R is quite depends on platform. For example comments at the beginning of `times.c` explains:

> Function clock() is C99 and defined in `time.h`.  It measures CPU
>       time at CLOCKS_PER_SEC: there is a small danger of integer
>       overflow.
>
> Function times() is POSIX and defined in `sys/times.h`.  It
>       returns the elapsed time in clock ticks, plus CPU times in a
>       struct tms* argument (also in clock ticks).

So answer is: measurement method may be different but units of measurement and the measured value are defined the same way, thus it does not matter, this is `clock()` as per `C99` or `times()` as per POSIX - IT IS CPU Time.